# how to load javascript file from absolute network path

Tags: javascript, file

Is there a way i can define my script tag to use absolute path instead of relative path so that my JavaScript files are loaded from a network location?

This is what i have tried:

```
<script src="file:\\\MyDFSDirectory\Test\TestApp\Scripts\jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```

This does not work. in FF, i get the error Security Error: `Content at http://localhost/Test/Test.html may not load or link to file:\\\MyDFSDirectory\Test\TestApp\Scripts\jquery-1.7.1.js`

In IE, I dont see the file being downloaded. In Network Tab (IE Dev Toolbar), it shows `Received 0 B`. If i take the URL and paste it in the File Explorer, it opens the JS file.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Try to host js file locally also. Using different protocols might (and should) throw security warnings.

Comment: If i wanted to host them locally, i would not have put them on network drive. :)

Comment: @Asdfg, but I'm not sure what you're expecting. Web browsers serve files via the protocols defined. You could "spoof" the file by using an HTTP handler at a specific URL (e.g. .../jquery), which then on the web server went and retrieved the file from the UNC path. That's the only real option you have. Consider the constraints you're working in.

Comment: @Asdfg than you will be restricted by browser security.

Answer (score 4):

You are indeed running up against the security model of the browsers. The only way around this is to run a web server locally and serve up the files that way.

Comment: That is an option but i am trying to avoid it.

Comment: It's so easy to run a quick web server these days. Python, PHP, Node... They all have quick command-line web servers that you can just fire up with minimal pain.

Comment: Problem is not to get the web server up and running. Its the replication that has to happen to all the regions. Adding one more component to the maintenance is what i am trying to avoid.

Comment: I'm also assuming that you're not just trying to load jQuery here, and that you're merely using that as an example. But, using a CDN for loading jQuery (or any other file) would obviate the need to run a web server as well.

Comment: @Asdfg some browsers allow to avoid that, e.g: in IE - you can manage security levels - but this will work only for individual use, most users prefer to have default settings.

Comment: What i am doing is to remove the dependency on the google CDN. I thought if i can simply create a file share and give "read" access to everyone and let them reference the files from there, i can do that since my domain controller will take care of the closest location of the DFS share. But it looks like i will have to go over http.